# Relation does not exist error when overriding get_queryset method of models.Manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have a model for storing music and it has `last_queried_at` field that is used for deleting the music object if not queried for a month.

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset.update(last_queried_at=timezone.now())
        return queryset

class Music(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="music/")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_queried_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="music",
    )
    objects = CustomManager()
```

When I try to make migrations it throws an error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_music" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "app_music" SET "last_queried_at" = '2...
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out how to solve this problem

I tried to use django's makemigrations command and threw an error. I was expecting it to create migrations.

Comment: Have you tried removing `use_in_migrations = True` in your manager ?

Comment: @Alombaros Yes, the same error.